# GCP - Identify which IAM user executes a Cloud SQL connection in the logs

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-iam, cloud-sql-proxy

We would like to identify which IAM user executes a Cloud SQL Proxy connection in the logs.
However, we can see this message:

```
  "textPayload": "2022-11-14 10:41:29.849 UTC [358324]: [1-1] db=[unknown],user=[unknown] LOG:  connection received: host=[local]",
```

We have the following flags enabled in the Postgres database:

- cloudsql.enable_pgaudit = ON
- pgaudit.log = all
- log_connections = On
- log_disconnections = On

We would like to know what other missing properties we need to set to have that "db" and "user" fields populated properly.

Extra info: https://medium.com/google-cloud/correlate-statement-logs-in-cloudsql-for-postgres-with-connection-sessions-5bae4ade38f5

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have activated the IAM authentication?

Comment: Yes, we have the IAM authentication flag set to ON in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The following flags worked for me

[image]

[image]

Note: don't forget to activate audit logs also

Adv filter:

```
resource.type="cloudsql_database"
"user=dan2"
```